# Convert ASCII output to human readable form and assign to a variable

Tags: arduino-mega, rfid, convert

I'm reading the RFID output and I can print it to the serial monitor as human readable. But what I want is to assign that to a variable. But I'm getting the ASCII. Is there any way to convert it and get to the variable like Serial.write() do.

```
byte readbackblock[19];

for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)//print the block contents
    {
      Serial.write (readbackblock[j]);
      cardNumber += readbackblock[j];
    }

Serial.print(cardNumber);
```

Serial output

```
read block: 1234567890123456

49505152535455565748495051525354
```

Any help please.

Comment: What do you mean "assign that to a variable"? It **is** in a variable already or you wouldn't be able to print it. It looks like the variable is called `readbackblock`.

Comment: I want to convert this ASCII `49505152535455565748495051525354` number to this `1234567890123456`. I can do that on the Serial.write(), but what I wan't is to send the output to some other without printing on the Serial.

Comment: @Majenko thank you very much, that did the trick :) (Y)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible.

The Arduino is 8-bit microcontroller, and can't handle integers larger than 32-bit. The maximum value for a unsigned 32-bit integer is 4294967296. This is a smaller number than your readblock, so it wil never fit.

If you want to do this with smaller numbers, you can use these 2 function:

- atoi -> convert char array to integer
- atol -> convert char array to long integer

Comment: *Can't handle* is a bit of a long bow to draw. I have [a sketch here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11519) that calculates `3^160 = 21847450052839212624230656502990235142567050104912751880812823948662932355201` - now that's quite a big number. The issue isn't the size of the number.

Comment: The issue isn't how to "assign to a variable". The issue is something else. Perhaps the question could be clarified?

Comment: I want to convert this ASCII 49505152535455565748495051525354 number to this 1234567890123456. I can do that on the Serial.write(), but what I wan't is to send the output to some other without printing on the Serial